# Spotfire Ironpython - Update a document property based on selection of another document property in drop down list

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I am trying to make a complex data condition where the filter should be applied only if a property value is set for the logic.

[image]

In the below screenshot, I am trying to set a condition where if the Business in dropdown is (None), then the Business Filter will be set to TRUE using Ironpython script.

[image]

The iron python script is below:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

If Document.Properties["Business"] == NULL:
    Return Document.Properties["BusinessFilter"] = TRUE
ELSE
    Return Document.Properties["BusinessFilter"] = FALSE
```

But the code isnt working. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax issues, this worked for me (setting the script to be executed when the property 'Business' changes value)

```
if Document.Properties["Business"] == None:
     Document.Properties["BusinessFilter"] = True
else:
     Document.Properties["BusinessFilter"] = False
```

if/else seem to have to be lowercase (you notice they are right when they turn blue in the editor); you need : after else, you don't need Return; and True and False need to be in Python format (so not TRUE but True) if you want a boolean property. The code worked without the imports on top.

Comment: Hi Gaia,
 
Thanks for the above solution. I have a new problem now, that when I set Business to a value other than None. It is not setting the BusinessFilter Document to False. 

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: can you post more details about what you do and what happens?

Comment: So basically, I need a data filtering interface where only when any Business is selected from drop down [10 items in drop down], the data table to the right of filter would be filtered based on the business selected. 

If the Business is none, I want to show all data based on previous filters - ie Report date & Country of Risk. (note - Report Date & Country of Risk are mandatory filters. where Business is optional filter)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to obtain the desired filtering logic using the below code easily.

Now I am able to filter data using "Business" filter when selected otherwise go for all data to be visible.

[image]